# How to configure config-file-provider files using configuration-as-code plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, yaml, jenkins-plugins

I have been following [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/tree/master/demos/config-file-provider) to configure config-file-provider files using the configuration-as-code plugin. 
Provided below is a sample YAML code I have used.

```
unclassified:
 globalConfigFiles:
  configs:
  - custom:
      id: custom-test
      name: DummyCustom1
      comment: dummy custom 1
      content: dummy content 1
```

I want to know whether there is a way to give **content** as a file(or file path).

Any help on how to fix this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. It's not CasC specific, it's just config-file-provider plugin not offering it.